# What are the killer applications of ChainMapper and ChainReducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I somehow can't figure out what are the use case for ChainMapper (map -> map -> map -> reduce) and ChainReducer (reduce -> map -> map -> map) compared to the usual chained tasks (map -> reduce -> map -> reduce).  Are there canonical examples or killer applications which use either of them? Or, are there some well-known systems / applications use either of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they are suitable for those cases when in a job pipeline there are few steps where-in either IdentityMapper or IdentityReducer is being used.

Consider this, you have 2 job steps in a given pipeline:

- Step1
- Step2

Now, Step1 uses an IdentityReducer. So output of Step 1 will be written to disk and then will be picked by Step2. To simplify this process ChainMapper helps to eliminate this copying to disk and reading in the Step2's mapper.

So, Step1 can become the first mapper M1 and Step2's mapper can become the second mapper M2.
So it would now look like [ M1 -> M2 -> R2 ].

Now as for the practical example, there is very common use-case where-in one needs to filter out records and then get into processing it. You may argue that why can't we do both the processing as well as filtering in the same mapper, I would say because of 2 reasons:

1 - Separation of concern

2 - What if you already have a pipeline ready and you just need to append a pre-processing step to it, Chain Mapper would come in handy.